# GRPC design of a current REST API

Tags: rest, protocol-buffers, grpc, api-design

I'm looking at the posibility of porting a lot of our REST API services to a `gRPC` schema, but here is the thing.

We currently make heavy use of one method of the API, that makes calls to multiple PostgreSQL functions based on the name of the function received as a parameter and the input as the body of the request, ie: `api.com/functions/exec/{name}`, the functions defined in the DB recieves and returns JSON.

So, if I understood well, a `gRPC` method can only have a static data structure both for receiving and returning types. How can i make it flexible?, because depends on the DB function to be called the data structure to be returned and sent as input

The structure returned by the API is something like

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "data": {
    "some": "value"
  },
  "status": "Correct..blabla"
}
```

---

The structure of the data sent to the API depends on the mode to be used if it's encrypted the request body will be a binary string

```
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
```

---

if it's not encrypted then it's just common JSON

```
{
  "one": "parameter"
}
```

---

One possible solution that I can think of, is to use always a type `byte`, both on the request and the response types, the only thing that I have to do is convert JSON to a binary string and vice-versa right?

I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs and performance requirements, going the raw bytes route might be sensible, if you really don't have any other uses for protobuf fields. If you do, you might want to define a message type that supports encrypted and unencrypted message fields like: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/proto/grpc/reflection/v1alpha/reflection.proto#L77